# Symfony 2 query builder join without relation (cross join)

Tags: symfony, dql

I am trying to use the query builder to join 2 tables which have no relation.

Desired end result:

```
SELECT x, y
FROM x
JOIN y
```

Query builder code:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('x');
$qb->from('Test1', 'x');
$qb->join('Test2', 'y');
$qb->orderBy('x.name', 'ASC');
```

Produces the following DQL:

`SELECT x FROM Test1 x INNER JOIN Test2 y ORDER BY x.name ASC`

Which results in a syntax error:

`[Syntax Error] line 0, col 137: Error: Expected Literal, got 'BY'`

The entities Test1 and Test2 don't have a relation (not in the code, nor in the database).

Is there any way to accomplish this?
I would like to use the query builder, because I have a lot of other functionality for the query that depends on the query builder (for filtering and sorting etc.).

I know this is possible with plain SQL, or DQL queries (not produced by the query builder).

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following possibility:

```
public function getYourData($users) {
    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
        ->select('x', 'y')
        ->from('Test1', 'x')
        ->leftJoin(
            'Test2',
            'y',
            \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
            'x.id = y.reference_id'
        )
        ->orderBy('x.name', 'ASC');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: But there is no relation. So x doesnt relate to y

Comment: Don't understand why you want to sort absolutely 2 different tables as a single one ? This is very bad design practice.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want. I have a table with domains, and a table with parameters. I want a result set with a list of all parameters for all domains.

Comment: The solution is achievable but not with only doctrine, you will need to query for the domains and for the parameters, transform them to arrays, then merge in a single one. With sorting thought (you can sort both arrays as you want before merging either way they don't have any relationship)

Comment: The reason i want to have the results in SQL (instead of merging arrays in PHP), is the extra (sub)queries that will be performed to find the values for domain/parameter combination. And i need pagination, filtering and sorting for those values. 

I understand that this is probably not do-able in DQL, I opened this question to be sure it is not possible.

Comment: Nope I don't see how can you achieve that with only DQL